# Getting List of Employees under Head and sub heads

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I want to get a list of employees who come under the given Head/Employee.

It should return all sub-heads and their sub-head and employees under him/her.

Following is the list of all Employees with their designations.

| EmpID | Name | Designation | HeadEmpID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CEO | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | CountryHead-USA | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | CountryHead-UK | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | StateHead-USA-A | 3 | 2 |
| 5 | StateHead-USA-B | 3 | 2 |
| 6 | StateHead-UK-C | 3 | 3 |
| 7 | ZoneHead-A | 9 | 6 |
| 8 | ZoneHead-B | 9 | 6 |
| 9 | ZoneHead-C | 9 | 4 |
| 10 | CityHead-A | 12 | 7 |

Lets say we ask  Who comes under 'CountryHead-UK'?
It should return

| EmpID | Name | Designation | Head |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | CountryHead-UK | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | StateHead-UK-C | 3 | 3 |
| 7 | ZoneHead-A | 9 | 6 |
| 8 | ZoneHead-B | 9 | 6 |
| 10 | CityHead-A | 12 | 7 |

If we ask who should come under CEO, then it should return everyone (for this sample data)

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #A
CREATE TABLE #A (EmpID int,Name VARCHAR(MAX), Designation INT, HeadEmpID INT)
INSERT INTO #A VALUES (1,'CEO',1,0)
INSERT INTO #A VALUES (2,'CountryHead-USA',2,1)
INSERT INTO #A VALUES (3,'CountryHead-UK',2,1)

INSERT INTO #A VALUES (4,'StateHead-USA-A',3,2)
INSERT INTO #A VALUES (5,'StateHead-USA-B',3,2)
INSERT INTO #A VALUES (6,'StateHead-UK-C',3,3)

INSERT INTO #A VALUES (7,'ZoneHead-A',9,6)
INSERT INTO #A VALUES (8,'ZoneHead-B',9,6)
INSERT INTO #A VALUES (9,'ZoneHead-C',9,4)

INSERT INTO #A VALUES (10,'CityHead-A',12,7)

SELECT * FROM #A a
```

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/YZH65Xvi

Comment: Have you looked at a recursive Common Table Expressio  (rCTE)? What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Larnu for a hint.

Follwing worked.

```
with cte as (
     select e.Empid, e.Name, e.Head, b.Name N1, b.Head new_boss
     from #a e
     left  join #a b on b.Empid = e.Head
     union all 
     select c.Empid, c.Name, c.new_boss, e.name, e.head
     from cte c 
     join #a e on e.Empid = c.new_boss
)

select Empid, Name, Head, N1 
from cte WHERE n1 = 'CountryHead-UK'
order by Empid, head
```